# Adding lcov to Hudson

Tags: hudson, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

rather new to Hudson here. I was wondering, how would one integrate [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov/readme.php) with it? How would I install the tarball into a Hudson job?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jenkins (or Hudson) can run anything you can run from the command line as part of the build process.

If you specifically want to use LCOV, you can:

- Install LCOV on the build server, add a build step that executes it and archive the artifacts.
- Add an LCOV installation into your repository and add a similar build step.

If you're after a code coverage tool, the [Cobertura](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cobertura+Plugin) plugin might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I used the [gcovr](https://software.sandia.gov/trac/fast/wiki/gcovr) to create the xml that Cobertura plugin was looking for...

Comment: having a lot of issues with gcovr. Its seems to want to do its own thing not what i want

Comment: Another option is the [lcov_cobertura](https://github.com/eriwen/lcov-to-cobertura-xml) script to turn LCOV results into Cobertura-compatible XML for Jenkins' Cobertura plugin.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the Cobertura plugin to lcov because it presents the results directly in each build report and doesn't copy the entire source code for each build. The information they present is very similar.

Unfortunately, it doesn't support gcov directly, but there is a Python script called gcovr that produces Cobertura-compatible output for Jenkins. [This article](http://meekrosoft.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/continuous-code-coverage-with-gcc-googletest-and-hudson/) explains how to set it up.

You can also run both coverage tools on each build, since they both use the same input from gcc.

Comment: Could Cobertura work with Objective-C programs- specifically, iOS apps?